# How can i forward email based on the email subject?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, contact-form-7

I need to forward emails coming from the `Contact form 7 plugin` to a group of users based on the email subject.

Lets say that i have an email with the subject "Services page form", now i need to forward this to an email `services@example.com`.

But if the email subject is "Contact page form", then i will forward it to `contact@example.com`. Are there any suggestions how this could be done?

If there are any other ways to do this are welcomed too.

Comment: look this to let the user choose the recipient https://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/

Answer (score 0):

Create different forms to use on each page. Each form you create has its own individual settings for email delivery etc.

Comment: I am already creating the subject dynamically to include the form page title in the email subject, so i want to extend this to automatically send emails to a group of users based on this subject.

Comment: Seems like a lot of work when all you have to do is click duplicate in CF7, change the email address you want the new form to send to and then change the shortcode on the page the new form goes on.

Comment: What if i had 200 different emails with different subjects?

Comment: If you had 200 then the best bet would probably be to train your staff to be able to deal with more than one type of enquiry. There are many ways to achieve what you want, if you already generate the subject dynamically why cant you generate an email address in the same way and have it inserted into a hidden field, then use that tag in CF7 for the to address? Create filtering rules in your mailserver? Use CF7 context values?

Comment: Can you elaborate "use that tag in CF7 for the to address? Create filtering rules in your mailserver? Use CF7 context values?"